# Keep getting "message": "'from' parameter is missing" in Rest API client

Tags: rest, http, mailgun, insomnia

I want to send a mail through Mailgu n with Insomnia. This is what I have done:

1. Created account at mailgun.com
2. Added a verified recipient:
   [image]
3. Opened up Insomnia and added the following configuration:
   [image]

3.1 This is the complete 'from':

```
from=sandboxcXXXXXX0a25422c87fdc18e0e6f8778.mailgun.org&to=VerifiedUser@hotmail.com&subject=subb&text=sometext
```

4. This is the auth. I got the auth key from Mailgun (Settings -> API Key -> Private API keys)
   [image]
5. This is the header:
   [image]
6. When I click on 'Send' this is the error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your Form Encoded data shouldn't be one string. It should be all key-value pairs like:

[image]